# Is there internal diagram of Zvezda or information about the internal size of Zvezda?

Tags: iss, design, roscosmos, zvezda

I found a diagram of Zvezda showing the external features, but I can't find one showing the internal features. Does an easily obtainable diagram exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not so much diagrams exist, but I found old one (with annotations in Russian):

https://cont.ws/uploads/pic/2017/12/2014-mks_07.jpg
[image]

from [this](https://cont.ws/@proctotanya/784810) page.

I am not sure is it official data from manufacturer or work by space fans...

---

**Translation of the annotations** (beginnig from the *right*, clockwise):

Переходная камера - *transition chamber*

Переходной люк - *transition hatch*

Огнетушитель - *fire extinguisher*

Агрегатный отсек - *aggregate [service] compartment*

Место установки бегущей дорожки - *place for a treadmill*

Пылесборник - *dust collector*

Место установки велоэргомера - *bicycle trainer placement site*

Иллюминаторы - *portholes*

Центральный пост управления - *central control post*

Переходной отсек - *transition chambe*r

Переходной люк - *transition hatch*

Аппаратура стыковки в ручном режиме - *manual-mode docking equipment [TORU]*

Противогаз - *gas mask*

Блок очистки атмосферы - *air purification unit*

Твердотопливные генераторы кислорода - *solid fuel oxygen generators*

Каюта - *crewmember's cabin*

Отсек санитарного устройства - *sanitary unit*

Comment: Your answer indicates the translations begin from the left of the image and proceed clockwise, but they appear to begin from the right of the image and proceed clockwise.

Comment: @Kamil Drakari - yes, it's my mistake, sorry. I have edited the answer